# Example of endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Endomorphism $T$ is linear mapping from one linear space to itself.

Let us consider $V=span\{e^x,\sin x, \cos x, \sin(2x), \cos (2x)\}$. It is easy to verify, that vectors $e^x,\sin x, \cos x, \sin(2x), \cos (2x)$ form a basis in V. We have the mapping $T(f)=f''+f$. Is it an endomorphism?

My solution is as follow:

This mapping is linear(it is easy to verify).

To check second part of definition let $g\in V$, then $$\exists a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\in\mathbb R: g=a_1e^x+a_2\sin x +a_3\cos x+a_4\sin(2x)+a_5\cos (2x).$$ Then
$$Tg=2a_1e^x-3a_4\sin (2x)-3a_5\cos(2x).$$ So $Im T=span\{e^x,\sin(2x),\cos(2x)\}\subset V$, and that mean that $T$ is not an endomorphism. (because $ImT\neq V$) Am I right in my consideration? I would be grateful for your hints and advices.

Comment: You are right - i forgot "," beetwen $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. Is that now ok?

Comment: Is that the product $\sin x \cos x$? If so $V$ is only 4 dimensional due to a linear dependence from the double angle formula. It looks like you treated it not as a product later though.

Comment: It was my mistake, it is not a product.

Comment: You're making a confusion in terminology. It seems that you're confusing endomorphism with automorphism. An endomorphism needs not to be onto.

Comment: Rather than calculating $T(g)$ you can note that $D(f) = f'$ is an endomorphism and $T = D^2 + I$. That way $D(g)$ is slightly less tedious to compute. Basically just need to check $f'$ is in $V$ for each basis vector.

Answer (score 1):

Any linear map $V\to V$ is called an endomorphism, it needs not be surjective.

Surjective endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space are exactly the invertible ones, the automorphisms.

Comment: So that mean, that my mapping is endomorphism, because for any $g\in V$ we have $T(g)\in V$ (suriecivity is not necessary). Thank for your help,

Comment: Exactly. ${{{}}}$